# DJango mysite/urls.py not including correctly

Tags: python, django, url

I am currently trying to write my first DJango following this tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/

I ran into an issue where I get a page not found at /.

My mysite/urls.py is the following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And polls.urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

However, if I change this in settings.py

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
```

to

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'polls.urls'
```

It works. What am I doing wrong, I am literally following the tutorial.

Comment: You have to use `path('', include('polls.urls')),` instead of `path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),`. Or add `path('', views.index, name='index'),`

Comment: Damn, of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'` and in mysite.urls.py use `path('', include('polls.urls'))`